# Selenium + Xvfb concurrency issues

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, xvfb

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
import sys

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
try:
    capabilities = webdriver.common.desired_capabilities.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chrome-driver/chromedriver', desired_capabilities=capabilities)
    try:
        browser.get('http://example.com')
        browser.execute_script('return 1 + 1;')
    finally:
        browser.quit()
finally:
    display.stop()
print 'Done'
```

And then run

```
seq 1 20 | parallel -j 5 ./test.py
```

I get a random number of errors like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 15, in <module>
    browser.execute_script('return 1 + 1;')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute_script
    {'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=50.0.2661.86)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371461 (633e689b520b25f3e264a2ede6b74ccc23cb636a),platform=Linux 3.19.0-59-generic x86_64)
```

If I remove the concurrency (`parallel -j 1`), it works.

If I remove Xvfb, it works.

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it (without giving up concurrency or virtual displays)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like starting `xvfb` has concurrency issues when starting. [xvfb-run unreliable when multiple instances invoked in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332137/xvfb-run-unreliable-when-multiple-instances-invoked-in-parallel)

So I can fix this by requiring that xfvb sessions are started serially.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import fcntl
import os
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
import xvfbwrapper

display = None
browser = None
try:
    with open('/tmp/xvfb.lock', 'w') as lock:
        fcntl.lockf(lock, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
        display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
        display.start()
        capabilities = webdriver.common.desired_capabilities.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        browser = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chrome-driver/chromedriver', desired_capabilities=capabilities)
    browser.get('http://example.com')
    browser.execute_script('return 1 + 1;')
finally:
    if browser:
        browser.quit()
    if display:
        display.stop()
print 'Done'
```

As long as everybody uses `/tmp/xvfb.lock` to control starting a Xvfb session starting, this works.

P.S. I don't think the selenium driver starting needed to be serialized too, but I did run into a transient problem that I think was fixed by this.