# Python cv2.imshow not working in vscode online

Tags: python, docker, opencv

I'm using Visual Studio Code online.

I tried to use `opencv` with `imshow` function, but I got the following error:

> Python cv2.imshow() not working: cannot connect to X server

- Is there a way for building a docker with display options?
- Or some other workaround to use this function?

Comment: Did you look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840184/python-code-crashes-with-cannot-connect-to-x-server-when-detaching-sshtmux-se)?

Comment: Have you looked at this page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container/25280523#25280523. maybe it can make some help.

Comment: Nope both didnt work, i am using vscode on web. and i am trying to use opencv in order to see images