# variable string that outputting as file name

Tags: bash, variables

I am trying to output stored variable as a file name. However only one variable is displayed in the file name. `$1` is `"HH"` on the command line and filecount is equal to `13`.  The output file name is `2019-07-24-16:44:56.csv`. I can not get the `"HH"` in the beginning of the file name.  I would like to see a file as sure `HH_2019-07-24-16:44:56-13.csv`. I am missing something?

```
#count the number of html email files in current directory
filecount=$(ls -1 *.html | grep -v '/$' | wc -l)
#Current date file is created
filedate=$(date +%F-%T)
filename="$jobtype$filedate-$filecount.csv"
echo $jobtype >> $filename
echo $filecount >> $filename
echo $filedate >> $filename
```

Comment: #count the number of html email files in current directory
filecount=$(ls -1 *.html | grep -v '/$' | wc -l)

#Current date file is created
filedate=$(date +%F-%T)

filename="$jobtype$filedate-$filecount.csv"

echo $jobtype >> $filename
echo $filecount >> $filename
echo $filedate >> $filename

Comment: @DaltonCézane, this probably goes for your question as formatted code block. Can you edit your question and remove your comment?

Comment: Please read [BashFAQ/004](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) and [don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). I don't see you using `$1` in your code. You may need to do `jobtype=$1`. Also, [quote your variables](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: BTW, every time you run a command with `>> $filename` on the end, it opens the file at the start of that command and closes it after it. Much more efficient to open it once and hold it open; `exec 3>"$filename"`, for example, and then anything you send `>&3` will be appended there without needing to reopen the file first.

Comment: ...another note -- this code currently has race conditions; two versions can get the same `filecount` if they both are running `ls` at the same time and neither one actually got to where it's creating the new file yet. That's not a theoretical concern -- it causes people real-world problems; see f/e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332137/xvfb-run-unreliable-when-multiple-instances-invoked-in-parallel

Comment: ...the immediate impetus for the question, though, just looks like a missing `jobtype=$1`.